# What is UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>? How to modify the underlying memory?

Tags: ios, pointers, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to work with SpriteKit's [`SKMutableTexture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKMutableTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKMutableTexture/modifyPixelDataWithBlock:) class but I don't know how to work with `UnsafeMutablePointer< Void >`. I have a vague idea that it is a pointer to a succession of byte data in memory. But how can I update it? What would this actually look like in code?

**Edit**

Here is a basic code sample to work with. How would I get this to do something as simple as create a red square on the screen?

```
    let tex = SKMutableTexture(size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    tex.modifyPixelDataWithBlock { (ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, n:UInt) -> Void in

        /* ??? */

    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs for `SKMutableTexture.modifyPixelDataWithBlock`:

> The texture bytes are assumed to be stored as tightly packed 32 bpp, 8bpc (unsigned integer) RGBA pixel data. The color components you provide should have already been multiplied by the alpha value.

So, while you’re given a `void*`, the underlying data is in the form of a stream of 4x8 bits.

You could manipulate such a structure like so:

```
// struct of 4 bytes
struct RGBA {
    var r: UInt8
    var g: UInt8
    var b: UInt8
    var a: UInt8
}

let tex = SKMutableTexture(size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
tex.modifyPixelDataWithBlock { voidptr, len in
    // convert the void pointer into a pointer to your struct
    let rgbaptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA>(voidptr)

    // next, create a collection-like structure from that pointer
    // (this second part isn’t necessary but can be nicer to work with)
    // note the length you supply to create the buffer is the number of 
    // RGBA structs, so you need to convert the supplied length accordingly...
    let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: rgbaptr, count: Int(len / sizeof(RGBA))

    // now, you can manipulate the pixels buffer like any other mutable collection type
    for i in indices(pixels) {
        pixels[i].r = 0x00
        pixels[i].g = 0xff
        pixels[i].b = 0x00
        pixels[i].a = 0x20
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this with the sample SpriteKit project in Xcode and seems to do the right thing – but I know _nothing_ about SpriteKit so can’t guarantee this is “the way” to do it.

Comment: Thank you this is working. I now see a square on screen however, I was expecting the modifyPixelDataWithBlock method to be called once per frame--like some sort of alternative to a fragment shader but the block is only called once. More digging...

Comment: Note that you need to pass in pre-multiplied by alpha values for the RGB part. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKMutableTexture_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKMutableTexture/modifyPixelDataWithBlock:) `The texture bytes are assumed to be stored as tightly packed 32 bpp, 8bpc (unsigned integer) RGBA pixel data. The color components you provide should have already been multiplied by the alpha value.`

Answer (score 8):

`UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` is the Swift equivalent of `void*` - a pointer to anything at all. You can access the underlying memory as its `memory` property. Typically, if you know what the underlying type is, you'll coerce to a pointer to that type first. You can then use subscripting to reach a particular "slot" in memory.

For example, if the data is really a sequence of UInt8 values, you could say:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(ptr)
```

You can now access the individual UIInt8 values as `buffer[0]`, `buffer[1]`, and so forth.

Comment: And see my Swift tutorial for more info: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_pointers

Comment: Judging by the method signature of [modifyPixelDataWithBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKMutableTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKMutableTexture/modifyPixelDataWithBlock:), I think the underlying type is an 8 bit integer. What would the cast actually look like in code? I'm really hoping for some code samples on how to do this

Comment: If it's an 8 bit integer, that would be an Int8 or UInt8. So if you cast to an UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> or UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, whichever it is, you can use subscripting to get at an individual byte by number.

Comment: What would I cast to an UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? Would you be so kind as to provide a simple code sample as a jumping off point? See my edit to the original question. Thank You!

Comment: Yes, sorry, when I said "cast" I should have said "coerce."