# How to Get a C Pointer's rawvalue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-text

I'm working on a project that uses CoreText; I need to initialize a `CTRunDelegateCallbacks`:

```
var  imageCallback =  CTRunDelegateCallbacks(version: kCTRunDelegateCurrentVersion, dealloc: { (refCon) -> Void in
    print("RunDelegate dealloc")
    }, getAscent: { ( refCon) -> CGFloat in
        return 0
    }, getDescent: { (refCon) -> CGFloat in
        return 0
    }) { (refCon) -> CGFloat in
        return 0
}
```

The parameter `refCon` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` type, which is  also called `void *` type in C. I want to get the pointer's raw value. How to do it?

Comment: What raw value you expect? Is it float, double?  So for ex, you can say let val = UnsafeMutablePointer<float>(refCon)  to extract the float value.  Also do take look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398677/what-is-unsafemutablepointervoid-how-to-modify-the-underlying-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend converting the pointer to a non-pointer type. I'll show you how to do it at the end of this answer, but first I'll show you how you should really handle `refCon`.

Create a struct to hold whatever information you need to pass through to the callbacks. Example:

```
struct MyRunExtent {
    let ascent: CGFloat
    let descent: CGFloat
    let width: CGFloat
}
```

Then create an `UnsafeMutablePointer` using its `alloc` class method, and initialize the allocated storage:

```
let extentBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<MyRunExtent>.alloc(1)
extentBuffer.initialize(MyRunExtent(ascent: 12, descent: 4, width: 10))
```

In your callbacks, convert the pointer argument to an `UnsafePointer<MyRunExtent>` and pull what you need out of its `memory`:

```
var callbacks = CTRunDelegateCallbacks(version: kCTRunDelegateVersion1, dealloc: { pointer in
    pointer.dealloc(1)
    }, getAscent: { pointer in
        return UnsafePointer<MyRunExtent>(pointer).memory.ascent
    }, getDescent: { pointer in
        return UnsafePointer<MyRunExtent>(pointer).memory.descent
    }, getWidth: { pointer in
        return UnsafePointer<MyRunExtent>(pointer).memory.width
})
```

Now you can create your delegate, using `callbacks` and `extentBuffer`:

```
let delegate = CTRunDelegateCreate(&callbacks, extentBuffer)!
```

Here's a test:

```
let richText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello \u{FFFC} world")
richText.addAttribute(kCTRunDelegateAttributeName as String, value: delegate, range: NSMakeRange(6, 1))
let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(richText)
let runs = (CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line) as [AnyObject]).map { $0 as! CTRun }
runs.forEach {
    var ascent = CGFloat(0), descent = CGFloat(0), leading = CGFloat(0)
    let width = CTRunGetTypographicBounds($0, CFRangeMake(0, 0), &ascent, &descent, &leading)
    print("width:\(width) ascent:\(ascent) descent:\(descent) leading:\(leading)")
}
```

The output (in a playground):

```
2015-12-21 12:26:00.505 iOS Playground[17525:8055669] -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f94bcb01dc0
width:28.6875 ascent:9.240234375 descent:2.759765625 leading:0.0
width:10.0 ascent:12.0 descent:4.0 leading:0.0
width:32.009765625 ascent:9.240234375 descent:2.759765625 leading:0.0
```

The first line of output is because the playground execution process can't encode the delegate to send back to Xcode for display, and turns out to be harmless. Anyway, you can see that the bounds of the middle run were computed using my callbacks and the content of my `extentBuffer`.

#### And now, the moment you've been waiting for…

You can get the pointer's “raw value” this way, **if** the pointer and an `Int` are the same size on the running system:

```
let rawValue = unsafeBitCast(refCon, Int.self)
```

If they're different sizes, you'll get a fatal error at runtime.

You could cast it to a `CGFloat` this way, **if** the pointer and a `CGFloat` are the same size:

```
let float = unsafeBitCast(refCon, CGFloat.self)
```

Comment: This solution is so elegant,I'm always wante to get the pointer's `raw value`,today I try to transfer a pointer of a CGFloat Array,it also doesn't work,transfer a stuct is better solution.Thanks again.

Comment: This does not work under Swift 3 now. Could you update for it? Thanks.